# using an exported sqlite database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to use my own sqlite3 database in my android project.

I created this database with command-shell line (windows) and exported it with [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) (sql format).

I followed this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728) and my database can't be open :

go [here to see](http://florian.delmas79.free.fr/Capturer.JPG) since i can't post image

My package is org.opencv.samples and my DBName is "maif" placed in /assets directory.

So it seems that my exported database is incorrect, can someone helps me ?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use this helper to solve your problems: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe you can transfer an external database through the file system to Android unless you have a rooted phone. If you have to transfer data you need to use data transfer via HTTP using XML/JSON.